# Why request.POST.get always empty in Django when using with react?

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I am using react with Django framework and not Django rest framework and when I send a post request from react side, the `request.POST.get('token', '')` is always empty.

```
token = request.POST.get("token")
```

I tried many things like `changing content type` using `request.data` instead but nothing is working.

Can anyone please tell Why I am not getting the post variable?

**EDIT**
This is js code that is being used to send post request.

```
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        responseType: 'json',
        url: `/auth/login/`,
        data: {
          'token':token,
          'username':'yesy'
        },
        headers:{
          'X-CSRFToken':csrf,
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }
      })
      .then((response:any) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error:any) => {
        //error.data.error.message
        console.log(error)
      });
```

Comment: Can you share your post request code?

Comment: @Daniel just made the edit please see.

Comment: But the name of the key is `id_token`, so you fetch it with `request.POST['id_token']`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry that was a typo. But I've edited the code.

Comment: But I guess i need to send multipart form data in request, but I guess its going json. May be if i send multipart form data it can work, but don't know how to make it work?

I tried "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", but this also didn't worked

Comment: What happens when you remove the "Content Type" key from your headers ?

Comment: @Daniel token = request.POST.get("token") token is null when i remove "Content Type"

Comment: Is there anything in `request.body` in your view function? Can you try printing this?

Comment: @Daniel Thankyou for your help, I actually managed to find the solution and posted the answer myself :)

Answer (score 1):

After some headbamging I managed to find the answer for it, If anyone stumbles upon this problem then just use `FormData` with multipart.

```
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('token', token);
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        responseType: 'json',
        url: `/auth/login/`,
        data: formData,
        headers:{
          'X-CSRFToken':csrf,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }
      })
      .then((response:any) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error:any) => {
        //error.data.error.message
        console.log(error)
      });
```

This solved mine problem, hence may be solve others too.